# Customizing Reponse in Serializer with Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models like,

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    counter = models.SmallIntegerField(db_column='counter', blank=False, default=0)

class ModelB(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, related_name='relation_a')
```

Serializer of ModelB. I am looking if there is already a row of ModelA in table ModelB. If there is any I increase the value in ModelA; otherwise, I create one and put the counter value 1 in ModelA. The response is the counter value coming from ModelA. The problem is, the response is the old value before executing this create function.

```
class ModelBSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    a = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True, source='a.counter')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            bInstance = ModelB.objects.get(a__id=validated_data.get('modelA').id)
            aInstance = ModelA.objects.get(pk=validated_data.get('a').id)
            aInstance.counter = 1
            aInstance.save()
        except DealThumbsCounter.DoesNotExist:
            bInstance = ModelB.objects.create(**validated_data)
            aInstance = ModelA.objects.get(pk=validated_data.get('modelA').id)
            aInstance.counter += 1
            aInstance.save()

        bInstance.save()
        return bInstance

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ['counter']
```

I am using drf-nested and url is

```
POST /modelA/{model_a_id}/modelB/
```

How can I get the updated counter value? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: you mean from `bInstance` return, you try `bInstance.a.counter` it get old value before increase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Ngoc Pham. The solution would be as follows,

```
class ModelBSerializer(BaseSerializer):
    a = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True, source='a.counter')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        try:
            bInstance = ModelB.objects.get(a__id=validated_data.get('modelA').id)
            aInstance = ModelA.objects.get(pk=validated_data.get('a').id)
            aInstance.counter = 1
            bInstance.a.counter = aInstance.counter
            aInstance.save()
        except DealThumbsCounter.DoesNotExist:
            bInstance = ModelB.objects.create(**validated_data)
            aInstance = ModelA.objects.get(pk=validated_data.get('modelA').id)
            aInstance.counter += 1
            bInstance.a.counter = aInstance.counter
            aInstance.save()

        bInstance.save()
        return bInstance

    class Meta:
        model = ModelB
        fields = ['counter']
```